# Karp reduction between FACTORING and a variant of it

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, factoring, np

Consider the following variant of the FACTORING problem (given N,M decide whether N has a prime factor less than M):

> MULTIPLE-FACTORING: Given three integers $1 \leq K \leq M \leq N$ decide if there are at least $K$ prime factors of $N$ less than $M$

FACTORING $\leq_m$ MULTIPLE-FACTORING (just pick $K=1$) and

MULTIPLE-FACTORING $\leq_T$ FACTORING (find all factors of $N$ using FACTORING, and count if their number is $\geq K$)

But is MULTIPLE-FACTORING many one reducible to FACTORING?
(MULTIPLE-FACTORING $\leq_m^?$ FACTORING)

Comment: What is the problem FACTORING? Given $N,M$, decide whether $M$ has a prime factor less than $M$? Also, when you say "factor" in MULTIPLE-FACTORING, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: yes factoring is "given N,M decide whether N has a prime factor less than M"; in MULTIPLE-FACTORING, "factors" mean prime factors. I should edit the question.

Comment: Do you count prime factors with multiplicity?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I'm interested in both versions: each prime factor is counted only once and prime factors are counted with their multiplicity (and the latter is a generalization of thr first version). To be honest I didn't think about it too much (it seems to me more like an "exercise", than an "unknown problem") :-(.

Comment: Well, you're unlikely to prove an answer of no as that would imply $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, but I think the answer should be no unless both problems are in $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: @usul why would yes and both problems not in P not be ok for you?